# Dynamically increase the column size in Text::TabularDisplay

Tags: perl

Currently I am using [Text::TabularDisplay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::TabularDisplay)
module in Perl.

I want to dynamically increase the number of columns in the table I have already created.

What I mean is, I want to populate the first column with data in first iteration and expand the table with second column and fill the contents in the second column and then again expand the table size until N<sup>th</sup> element dynamically.

At the end I want to render the table after N iterations.

Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: I think what you want to do is add one column at a time instead of one row at a time. The module does not have that functionality. You will have to reach in and add it. Or store the data somewhere else, then add it all at the same time, i.e. transpose yourself

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand, you can't render your table out without gathering all cols together anyway. After that it is not so hard to iterate over cols:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;
use Text::TabularDisplay;

my $cols = [
  [ qw/1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9/ ],
  [ qw/a b c d e f g h i/ ],
  [ qw/j k l m n o p q r/ ],
  [ qw/s t u v w x y z @/ ],
];

my $table = Text::TabularDisplay->new( qw/foo bar baz fod / );

# transpose columns to rows
# expect first column has max number of elements over all the columns
for ( my $row = 0; $row < scalar @{ $cols->[0] }; $row++ ) {
  $table->add(  map { $_->[ $row ] } @$cols );
}

say $table->render;
```